# Copy image to internal memory

Tags: android

How I copy a image to internal memory and recover after that?

Comment: What do  you mean recover?  Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the following combination of openFileOutput() and Bitmap.compress() to store the image to the internal storage.

```
// Create a BitMap object of the image to be worked with
final Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream( ..some image.. );

// The openfileOutput() method creates a file on the phone/internal storage in the context of your application 
final FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput("my_new_image.jpg", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

// Use the compress method on the BitMap object to write image to the OutputStream
bm.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, fos);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do it in a following way:

```
//read bitmap from resource
public InputStream getBitmapStreamFromResource(Context context, int recourceId)
{
    return context.getResources().getAssets().open(recourceId);
}


// convert stream into Bitmap
public Bitmap getBitmapFromStream(InputStream is)
{
    return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
}

//inflate bitmap in a given parent View
public View inflateToView(Context context, ViewGroup parent, Bitmap bitmap)
{
    ViewGroup layout=new LinearLayout(context);
    layout.setLayoutParams(new          ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    ImageView imageView=new ImageView(context);
    imageView.setEnabled(true);
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
    imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    layout.addView(imageView);
    parent.addView(layout);
    return layout;
}
```

Comment: I need to copy a image in the internal memory