# Image quality has been lost when taken from camera in android app

Tags: android, image

i take image from gallery and camera
when i upload image from camera it loss quality
but gallery image is in actual quality

from camera
[image]

from gallery
[image]

here is my code to upload image from camera and gallery

to get image from cam

```
    Intent in = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
 File out = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
 String fileName=GetFileName().replace('.', ' ')+".png";
 out = new File(out, fileName); 
in.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(out));
 startActivityForResult(in, cameraIdNotSdCard);

@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
//from camera
    wb.loadUrl(sendUrl);

        if (requestCode == cameraIdNotSdCard) {
            if (data != null && resultCode == RESULT_OK ) {
                bm = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");

                int width = 350;
                int height = 400;
                if (HomePage.permistionArray.length > 4) {

                    width = Integer.valueOf(HomePage.permistionArray[3]);
                    height = Integer.valueOf(HomePage.permistionArray[4]);
                }

                // Log.d("ddddddddddddd", width+":"+height);

                Bitmap resizeBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bm, width,
                        height, true);

                    ByteArrayOutputStream boas = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                // bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, boas);

                resizeBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG  ,100, boas);

                byte[] b = boas.toByteArray();
                imageS = Base64.encodeToString(b, 0);

                // call custom class which class web service in background which
                // save image ..
                new imageSaveClass(getApplicationContext()).execute();

            }
        }
        // form gallery result
           if (requestCode == galleryRsultCode && resultCode == RESULT_OK
                    && data != null) {

            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();


            String[] filePathColum = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    filePathColum, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColum[0]);

            String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);

            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory
                    .decodeFile(picturePath);
            if(myBitmap!=null)
            {
                int width = 350;
                int height = 400;
                if (HomePage.permistionArray.length > 4) {

                    width = Integer.valueOf(HomePage.permistionArray[3]);
                    height = Integer.valueOf(HomePage.permistionArray[4]);
                } 

                // Log.d("ddddddddddddd", width+":"+height);

                Bitmap resizeBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(myBitmap, width,
                        height, true);

                ByteArrayOutputStream boas = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                // bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, boas);

                resizeBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, boas);

                byte[] b = boas.toByteArray();
                imageS = Base64.encodeToString(b, 0);

                // call custom class which class web service in background which
                // save image ..
                new imageSaveClass(getApplicationContext()).execute();
            }

        }
```

i take image from gallery and camera
when i upload image from camera it loss quality
but gallery image is in actual quality

how i can improve quality from camera

Comment: inside onActivityResult you are getting the image for thumbnail purpose its not the actual image. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10779789/android-not-able-to-get-original-photo-captured-by-camera-able-to-read-compres

Comment: i use this code to get image from cam   Intent in = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
       File out = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
       String fileName=GetFileName().replace('.', ' ')+".png";
       out = new File(out, fileName);
       in.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(out));
       startActivityForResult(in, cameraIdNotSdCard);

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the compress format.

You are using for Camera:

```
 resizeBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG  ,100, boas);
```

And for Galery:

```
 resizeBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG ,100, boas);
```

Also read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7752936/562840).

Comment: did you find a solution ?