# Why camera image not saved in Android?

Tags: android, camera, image-capture

I have a button and when clicking on it, it will start camera and save image that I take, but something not working.
This code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12995185/android-taking-photos-and-saving-them-with-a-custom-name-to-a-custom-destinati) :

```
private void takeAPic() {
    //camera stuff
    Intent imageIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());

//folder stuff
        File imagesFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "MyImages");
        imagesFolder.mkdirs();

    File image = new File(imagesFolder, "QR_" + timeStamp + ".png");
    Uri uriSavedImage = Uri.fromFile(image);
    log("uriSavedImage: "+uriSavedImage.toString());
    imageIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriSavedImage);
    getActivity().startActivityForResult(imageIntent, Constant.REQUEST_CODE.TAKE_A_PIC);
}
```

Log: `uriSavedImage:file:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/MyImages/QR_20160104_165527.png`

Image that I take not saved on my phone and this app return null data:

```
{who=null, request=62, result=-1, data=Intent {  }}
```

In Manifest:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"></uses-feature>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

onActivity:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {        
    case Constant.REQUEST_CODE.TAKE_A_PIC:
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            setSystemImage(data);
        }
        break;
    default:
        break;
}



private void setSystemImage(Intent data) {
    Uri targetUri = data.getData();
    log("log: "+targetUri.toString());
    try {
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(targetUri));
        image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your onActivityResult code

Comment: I'm sure 62, switch (requestCode) {case Constant.REQUEST_CODE.TAKE_A_PIC: Uri targetUri = data.getData();
        log("log: "+targetUri.toString()); break;
            default:
                break;}

Comment: Edit your question and add the code

Comment: Ok, please check it again.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);` inside

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
}
```

like

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode) {
 }
}
```

Comment: Image that I take not saved on my phone and this app still return null data.