# How to call takePicture() method from another activity in android?

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I have main activity class where i have written takePicturefromCamera() method like this:

```
public void takePicturefromCamera() {
             Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                try {

                    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
                    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
                        mImageCaptureUri = Uri.fromFile(mFileTemp);
                    }
                    else {
                    //  The solution is taken from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10042695/how-to-get-camera-result-as-a-uri-in-data-folder

                        mImageCaptureUri = InternalStorageContentProvider.CONTENT_URI;
                    }   
                    intent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mImageCaptureUri);
                    intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_TAKE_PICTURE);
                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {

                    Log.d("TAG", "cannot take picture", e);
                }

        }
```

Now I have another class where i am doing some cropping part and my requirement is if while cropping user feels that he want to take some another picture instead of previous there i want to call above takePicturefromCamera() method of main activity class on some button click. Can anyone help me how can I do like this. I have tried by doing like this:

```
retake_button.setOnClickListener(
                     new View.OnClickListener() {
                         public void onClick(View v) {
                            // setResult(RESULT_CANCELED);
                           main m = new main();
                           m.takePicturefromCamera();
                         }
                     });
```

But it gives me error NullPointerException at `mImageCaptureUri = Uri.fromFile(mFileTemp);`

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to keep `takePicturefromCamera()` in separate class, and then call this method passing the activitycontext and data required to it.

Or else you can make `Activity2 extend Activity1` and use `takePicturefromCamera()`.

Comment: my activity2 alredy extends aother class

Comment: It will be very lengthy like from activity1 to activity2 and then from activity2 to activity3 and activity3 to acivitity1. Isnt it have any another solution???

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, could you plz elaborate? You can simplly call this method using the object of that class.

Comment: whenever i am creating object of class and calling method using that object its gives me NullPointerExecption at  Uri.fromFile(mFileTemp);

Answer (score 0):

Make that method as static so you can use it anywhere in your application.

Also add one more parameter "File" to your function. By this, you also have flexibility to use the same function for different file object in your application.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I tried by doing making it static but then problem occures at startActivityForresult(). As it doesnot support in static methods