# Android Galaxy Camera invoke camera app for continuous shot

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-camera

I'm using the first method outlined in this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/10229228) to invoke the camera app to let the user take a photo and return it to my app. What I want to do is get a series of photos from continuous (burst) shot mode, but invoking the camera app in this way only allows the user to take a single photo.

I have tried adding code to my app to use the camera directly with autofocus set to infinity however it doesn't get anywhere near the performance of continuous shot mode.

Is there something I can add to the intent I'm starting to tell it to use a different mode?

Comment: Can you access the camera directly?  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html

Comment: @fadden Yes, I tried accessing the camera directly and found that the speed with which I could take photos in succession is significantly slower than the continuous shot/burst mode function of the built in camera app.

Comment: Can you use the video recorder mode and just pull frames out of the encoded video?  You'd lose some quality because of the compression, but you can run at a high frame rate.  For Android 4.3 you might be able to use the surface preview to get frames faster, but at some point you have to copy the data into your app and save it off, and that's going to cost.  (See http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/ for some examples.)