# Handling data from intent after orientation change

Tags: android, image, android-intent, null, orientation

My app is set to only display in portrait mode. The problem is that I need to use a camera and a gallery intent and you can't specify those apps to be the same orientation so some funky stuff happens in between those orientation changes which makes my image data null.

This code works fine when the phone isn't tilted sideways (in portrait mode) how would I improve it to handle data after an orientation change?

```
public class PostPhotosActivity extends Activity {

public static final String TAG = "PostPhotosActivity";


String title, price, description, maincat, subcat, pname, pemail, pphone, pmeet, imageUri;

public static final String TEMP_PHOTO_FILE_NAME = "temp_photo.jpg";

public static final int REQUEST_CODE_GALLERY      = 0x1;
public static final int REQUEST_CODE_TAKE_PICTURE = 0x2;
public static final int REQUEST_CODE_CROP_IMAGE   = 0x3;
private ImageView mImageView;
private File      mFileTemp;
ParseFile file;
double latitude, longitude;
Button button;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);    //To change body of overridden methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_post_photos);



     Bundle extras= getIntent().getExtras();
     if(extras!=null)
     {
        title = extras.getString("TITLE"); // get the value based on the key
        price = extras.getString("PRICE"); // get the value based on the key 
        description = extras.getString("DESCRIPTION"); // get the value based on the key
        maincat = extras.getString("MAINCAT"); // get the value based on the key 
        subcat = extras.getString("SUBCAT"); // get the value based on the key
        pname = extras.getString("PNAME"); // get the value based on the key 
        pemail = extras.getString("PEMAIL"); // get the value based on the key
        pphone = extras.getString("PPHONE"); // get the value based on the key 
        pmeet = extras.getString("PMEET"); // get the value based on the key
    }  



button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.post_data);

button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Perform action on click

        GpsLocationTracker mGpsLocationTracker = new GpsLocationTracker(PostPhotosActivity.this);

         /**
              * Set GPS Location fetched address
              */
             if (mGpsLocationTracker.canGetLocation()) 
             {
                 latitude = mGpsLocationTracker.getLatitude();
                 longitude = mGpsLocationTracker.getLongitude();
                 Log.i(TAG, String.format("latitude: %s", latitude));
                 Log.i(TAG, String.format("longitude: %s", longitude));

             } 
             else 
             {
                 mGpsLocationTracker.showSettingsAlert();
             }

        ParseGeoPoint point = new ParseGeoPoint(latitude, longitude);
        ParseObject setPost = new ParseObject("testData");

        // Create an author relationship with the current user
        setPost.put("author", ParseUser.getCurrentUser());

        // Get location

        setPost.put("location", point);
        setPost.put("Title", title);
        setPost.put("Price", price);
        setPost.put("Description", description);
        setPost.put("MainCat", maincat);
        setPost.put("SubCat", subcat);
        setPost.put("PName", pname);
        setPost.put("PEmail", pemail);
        setPost.put("PPhone", pphone);
        setPost.put("PMeet", pmeet);
        setPost.put("Photo", file);

        setPost.saveInBackground();

        Intent intent = new Intent(PostPhotosActivity.this, Flow.class);
       startActivity(intent);
    }
});


    final String[] items = new String[] { "Take from camera",
            "Select from gallery" };
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, items);
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    builder.setTitle("Select Image");
    builder.setAdapter(adapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) { // pick from
                                                                // camera
            if (item == 0) {

                takePicture();

            } else { // pick from file

                openGallery();

            }
        }
    });

    final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();

    mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_photo);
    mImageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            dialog.show();
        }
    });



        String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
                mFileTemp = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), TEMP_PHOTO_FILE_NAME);
        }
        else {
                mFileTemp = new File(getFilesDir(), TEMP_PHOTO_FILE_NAME);
        }

}

private void takePicture() {

    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    try {
            Uri mImageCaptureUri = null;
            String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
            if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
                    mImageCaptureUri = Uri.fromFile(mFileTemp);
            }
            else {
                    /*
                     * The solution is taken from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10042695/how-to-get-camera-result-as-a-uri-in-data-folder
                     */
                    mImageCaptureUri = InternalStorageContentProvider.CONTENT_URI;
            }        
        intent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mImageCaptureUri);
        intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_TAKE_PICTURE);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {

        Log.d(TAG, "cannot take picture", e);
    }
}

private void openGallery() {

    Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
    photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
    startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, REQUEST_CODE_GALLERY);
}

private void startCropImage() {

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, CropImage.class);
    intent.putExtra(CropImage.IMAGE_PATH, mFileTemp.getPath());
    intent.putExtra(CropImage.SCALE, true);

    intent.putExtra(CropImage.ASPECT_X, 1);
    intent.putExtra(CropImage.ASPECT_Y, 1);

    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_CROP_IMAGE);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {

        return;
    }

    Bitmap bitmap;

    switch (requestCode) {

        case REQUEST_CODE_GALLERY:

            try {

                InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(data.getData());
                FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(mFileTemp);
                copyStream(inputStream, fileOutputStream);
                fileOutputStream.close();
                inputStream.close();

                startCropImage();

            } catch (Exception e) {

                Log.e(TAG, "Error while creating temp file", e);
            }

            break;
        case REQUEST_CODE_TAKE_PICTURE:

            startCropImage();
            break;
        case REQUEST_CODE_CROP_IMAGE:

            String path = data.getStringExtra(CropImage.IMAGE_PATH);
            if (path == null) {

                return;
            }

            //byte[] idata = path.getBytes();
            Bitmap picture = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            picture.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
            // get byte array here
            byte[] idata= stream.toByteArray();

            file = new ParseFile("photo.jpg", idata);
            file.saveInBackground();

            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mFileTemp.getPath());

            mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            break;
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}


public static void copyStream(InputStream input, OutputStream output)
        throws IOException {

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int bytesRead;
    while ((bytesRead = input.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }
}
]
```

Comment: You can save your data in a `sharedPreference`.
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref

Answer (score 0):

You could use fragments to retain the information that is being lost by the orientation change.

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidFragments/article.html#headlessfragments2