# How to fix this -> Unable to find explicit activity class

Tags: android, android-intent, android-asynctask, android-json

I have a fragment layout with list view from JSON, but when i click them, i got error.

```
06-13 13:17:58.492: E/AndroidRuntime(1542): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-13 13:17:58.492: E/AndroidRuntime(1542): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.yeftaandrea.plesirsolo/com.yeftaandrea.plesirsolo.KaranganyarAttractionDetailFragment}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
06-13 13:17:58.492: E/AndroidRuntime(1542):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1628)
06-13 13:17:58.492: E/AndroidRuntime(1542):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1424)
06-13 13:17:58.492: E/AndroidRuntime(1542):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3390)
06-13 13:17:58.492: E/AndroidRuntime(1542):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3351)
06-13 13:17:58.492: E/AndroidRuntime(1542):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityFromFragment(FragmentActivity.java:848)
06-13 13:17:58.492: E/AndroidRuntime(1542):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.startActivity(Fragment.java:878)
06-13 13:17:58.492: E/AndroidRuntime(1542):     at com.yeftaandrea.plesirsolo.KaranganyarAttractionFragment$1.onItemClick(KaranganyarAttractionFragment.java:80)
06-13 13:17:58.492: E/AndroidRuntime(1542):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
06-13 13:17:58.492: E/AndroidRuntime(1542):     at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1100)
06-13 13:17:58.492: E/AndroidRuntime(1542):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2788)
06-13 13:17:58.492: E/AndroidRuntime(1542):     at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3463)
06-13 13:17:58.492: E/AndroidRuntime(1542):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
06-13 13:17:58.492: E/AndroidRuntime(1542):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-13 13:17:58.492: E/AndroidRuntime(1542):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-13 13:17:58.492: E/AndroidRuntime(1542):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
06-13 13:17:58.492: E/AndroidRuntime(1542):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-13 13:17:58.492: E/AndroidRuntime(1542):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
06-13 13:17:58.492: E/AndroidRuntime(1542):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
06-13 13:17:58.492: E/AndroidRuntime(1542):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
06-13 13:17:58.492: E/AndroidRuntime(1542):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

this is my source code :

1.KaranganyarAttractionFragment

```
package com.yeftaandrea.plesirsolo;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.yeftaandrea.plesirsolo.adapter.KaranganyarJsonAttractionAdapter;

public class KaranganyarAttractionFragment extends Fragment {

    // URL to get contacts JSON
    // JSON Node names
    public static final String TAG_ID = "ID";
    public static final String TAG_NAME = "Name";
    public static final String TAG_ADDRESS = "Address";
    public static final String TAG_PHONE = "Phone";
    public static final String TAG_CITY = "City";
    public static final String TAG_DESCRIPTION = "Description";
    public static final String TAG_AKSESBILITAS = "Aksesbilitas";
    public static final String TAG_Tiket = "Tiket";
    public static final String TAG_FACILITIES = "Faclilities";
    public static final String TAG_LANTITUDE = "Lantitude";
    public static final String TAG_LONGTITUDE = "Longtitude";
    public static final String TAG_PICPATH = "PicPath";

    // Hashmap for ListView
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> attractionList;
    ListView list;

    KaranganyarJsonAttractionAdapter adapter;

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_attraction_karanganyar, container, false);

        list = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);

        list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                    long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.Name))
                        .getText().toString();
                String address = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.Address))
                        .getText().toString();
                String phone = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.Phone))
                        .getText().toString();

                Intent i = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), KaranganyarAttractionDetailFragment.class);

                i.putExtra("TAG_ID", id);               
                i.putExtra("TAG_NAME", name);   
                i.putExtra("TAG_ADDRESS", address);
                i.putExtra("TAG_PHONE", phone);     
                startActivity(i);
            }
            });

        // Calling async task to get json
        new LoadTask().execute();

        return rootView;
    }

    public void loadAttraction(){
        attractionList = new 
                ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        try {
            JSONArray attraction = parser.makeHttpRequestArray("http://plesirsolo.meximas.com/plesir/attraction/wisata/karanganyar/", "GET", params);
            // JSONArray attraction = parser.makeHttpRequestArray("http://192.168.56.1:8080/examples/json.html", "GET", params);
            // looping through All messages
            if(attraction!=null){
                for (int i = 0; i < attraction.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = attraction.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                    String nama = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                    String address = c.getString(TAG_ADDRESS);
                    String phone = c.getString(TAG_PHONE);
                    String picPath = c.getString(TAG_PICPATH);

                    // creating new HashMap
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    map.put(TAG_ID, id);
                    map.put(TAG_NAME, nama);
                    map.put(TAG_ADDRESS, address);
                    map.put(TAG_PHONE, phone);
                    map.put(TAG_PICPATH, picPath);

                    // adding HashList to ArrayList
                    attractionList.add(map);
                }

                adapter = new KaranganyarJsonAttractionAdapter(
                        getActivity(), attractionList);
            }


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private class LoadTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading Attraction ...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            loadAttraction();
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
            pDialog.dismiss();
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            list.setAdapter(adapter);
            Log.i("JSON", "TEST");
            Log.i("JSON", attractionList.toString());
        }       

    }

}
```

1. KaranganyarJsonAttractionAdapter

   public class KaranganyarJsonAttractionAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

   ```
   private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
   public ImageLoader imageLoader;
   private Context context;
   public String imageBaseDirectory  = "http://plesirsolo.meximas.com/plesir/images/wisata/";


   public KaranganyarJsonAttractionAdapter(Context context,
           ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> attractionList) {
       this.data = attractionList;
       this.context = context;
       imageLoader = new ImageLoader(context);
   }

   @Override
   public int getCount() {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       if(data != null)
           return data.size();
       return 0;
   }

   @Override
   public Object getItem(int position) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       return position;
   }

   @Override
   public long getItemId(int position) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       return position;
   }

   @Override
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       if (convertView == null) {
           LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                   .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
           convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row2, null);
       }

       TextView Name = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.Name); // name
       TextView Address = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.Address); // address
       TextView Phone = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.Phone); // phone
       ImageView PicPath = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_image); // thumb image

       HashMap<String, String> attraction = new HashMap<String, String>();
       attraction = data.get(position);

       Log.i("JSON", attraction.toString());

       // Setting all values in listview
       Name.setText(attraction.get(KaranganyarAttractionFragment.TAG_NAME));
       Address.setText(attraction.get(KaranganyarAttractionFragment.TAG_ADDRESS));
       Phone.setText(attraction.get(KaranganyarAttractionFragment.TAG_PHONE));

       Log.i("JSON", attraction.get(KaranganyarAttractionFragment.TAG_NAME));
       imageLoader.DisplayImage(imageBaseDirectory+attraction.get(KaranganyarAttractionFragment.TAG_PICPATH), position, PicPath);
       return convertView;
   }
   ```

   }
2. KaranganyarAttractionDetailFragment

   public class KaranganyarAttractionDetailFragment extends Fragment  {
       // URL to get contacts JSON
       // JSON Node names
       public static final String TAG_ID = "ID";
       public static final String TAG_NAME = "Name";
       public static final String TAG_ADDRESS = "Address";
       public static final String TAG_PHONE = "Phone";
       public static final String TAG_CITY = "City";
       public static final String TAG_DESCRIPTION = "Description";
       public static final String TAG_AKSESBILITAS = "Aksesbilitas";
       public static final String TAG_Tiket = "Tiket";
       public static final String TAG_FACILITIES = "Faclilities";
       public static final String TAG_LANTITUDE = "Lantitude";
       public static final String TAG_LONGTITUDE = "Longtitude";
       public static final String TAG_PICPATH = "PicPath";

   ```
   // Hashmap for ListView
   ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> attractionList;
   ListView list;

   KaranganyarJsonAttractionDetailAdapter adapter;

   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
           Bundle savedInstanceState) {

       View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_attraction_karanganyar_detail, container, false);

       // Calling async task to get json
       new LoadTask().execute();

       return rootView;


   }

   public void loadAttraction(){
       attractionList = new 
               ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
       JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

       List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

       try {
           JSONArray attraction = parser.makeHttpRequestArray("http://plesirsolo.meximas.com/plesir/attraction/wisata/karanganyar/", "GET", params);
           // JSONArray attraction = parser.makeHttpRequestArray("http://192.168.56.1:8080/examples/json.html", "GET", params);
           // looping through All messages
           if(attraction!=null){
               for (int i = 0; i < attraction.length(); i++) {
                   JSONObject c = attraction.getJSONObject(i);

                   // Storing each json item in variable
                   String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                   String nama = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                   String address = c.getString(TAG_ADDRESS);
                   String phone = c.getString(TAG_PHONE);
                   String picPath = c.getString(TAG_PICPATH);

                   // creating new HashMap
                   HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                   // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                   map.put(TAG_ID, id);
                   map.put(TAG_NAME, nama);
                   map.put(TAG_ADDRESS, address);
                   map.put(TAG_PHONE, phone);
                   map.put(TAG_PICPATH, picPath);

                   // adding HashList to ArrayList
                   attractionList.add(map);
               }

               adapter = new KaranganyarJsonAttractionDetailAdapter(
                       getActivity(), attractionList);
           }


       } catch (JSONException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }

   private class LoadTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

       @Override
       protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
           loadAttraction();
           return null;
       }

       @Override
       protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
           super.onPostExecute(result);
           list.setAdapter(adapter);
           Log.i("JSON", "TEST");
           Log.i("JSON", attractionList.toString());
       }       


   }
   ```

   }
3. KaranganyarJsonAttractionDetailAdapter

   public class KaranganyarJsonAttractionDetailAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

   ```
   private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
   public ImageLoader imageLoader;
   private Context context;
   public String imageBaseDirectory  = "http://plesirsolo.meximas.com/plesir/images/wisata/";

   public KaranganyarJsonAttractionDetailAdapter(Context context,
           ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> attractionList) {
       this.data = attractionList;
       this.context = context;
       imageLoader = new ImageLoader(context);
   }

   @Override
   public int getCount() {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       if(data != null)
           return data.size();
       return 0;
   }

   @Override
   public Object getItem(int position) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       return position;
   }

   @Override
   public long getItemId(int position) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       return position;
   }

   @Override
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       if (convertView == null) {
           LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                   .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
           convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_attraction_karanganyar_detail, null);
       }
       TextView Name = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.Name); // name
       TextView Address = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.Address); // address
       TextView Phone = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.Phone); // phone
       ImageView PicPath = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_image); // thumb image

       HashMap<String, String> attraction = new HashMap<String, String>();
       attraction = data.get(position);

       Log.i("JSON", attraction.toString());

       // Setting all values in listview
       Name.setText(attraction.get(KaranganyarAttractionDetailFragment.TAG_NAME));
       Address.setText(attraction.get(KaranganyarAttractionDetailFragment.TAG_ADDRESS));
       Phone.setText(attraction.get(KaranganyarAttractionDetailFragment.TAG_PHONE));

       Log.i("JSON", attraction.get(KaranganyarAttractionDetailFragment.TAG_NAME));
       imageLoader.DisplayImage(imageBaseDirectory+attraction.get(KaranganyarAttractionDetailFragment.TAG_PICPATH), position, PicPath);
       return convertView;

   }
   ```

   }
4. Manifest

   ```
   <uses-sdk
       android:minSdkVersion="14"
       android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

   <application
       android:allowBackup="true"
       android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
       android:label="@string/app_name"
       android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
       <activity
           android:name="com.yeftaandrea.plesirsolo.SplashScreen"
           android:label="@string/app_name" >
           <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

               <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
           </intent-filter>
       </activity>
       <activity
           android:name="com.yeftaandrea.plesirsolo.MainActivity"
           android:label="@string/app_name" >
       </activity>
   </application>

   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
   ```

Comment: post your manifest file.

Comment: i've post @TheTokenizer

Answer (score 0):

What you're most likely forgetting.

```
<activity
    android:name=".KaranganyarAttractionDetailFragment">
    </activity>
```

Copy and paste below code into manifest.

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.yeftaandrea.plesirsolo.SplashScreen"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
    android:name=".KaranganyarAttractionDetailFragment">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.yeftaandrea.plesirsolo.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
</application>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: on manifest ? I have a lot of classes like this, what I have to do all in the manifest?

Comment: When you create a new activity it must be specified in the manifest of the application

Comment: so much as any activity should be specified in the manifest of the application ?

Answer (score 0):

Use this method just add name for application.

```
<application
        android:name="com.yeftaandrea.plesirsolo"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

Answer (score -1):

Navigate to your AndroidManifest.xml file in your project directory. Place this line inbetween the `<application></application>` tags (which should have something similar in it).

```
<activity android:name=".KaranganyarAttractionDetailFragment"></activity>
```

Comment: on manifest ? I have a lot of classes like this, what I have to do all in the manifest?

Comment: Yes - you need to declare every Activity you will have in your Android application in the manifest @YeftaAndrea

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.yeftaandrea.plesirsolo/com.yeftaandrea.plesirsolo.KaranganyarAttractionDetailFragment}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.yeftaandrea.plesirsolo.KaranganyarAttractionDetailFragment cannot be cast to android.app.Activity

Comment: Try this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20576747/fragment-cannot-be-cast-to-android-app-activity
Your error is a little more complex than first thought

Comment: There is no activity class existing in his app/code.A fragment cannot be assigned to an activity in the manifest.Unless one extends ListFragment etc