# Android App doesn't run, crashes

Tags: android, crash

I have been messing around with this code:

```
package com.example.doblevxv5.sunny;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Encapsulates fetching the forecast and displaying it as a {@link ListView} layout.
 */
public class ForecastFragment extends Fragment {

    public ForecastFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Add this line in order for this fragment to handle menu events.
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.forecastfragment, menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_refresh) {
            FetchWeatherTask weatherTask = new FetchWeatherTask();
            weatherTask.execute();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Create some dummy data for the ListView.  Here's a sample weekly forecast
        String[] data = {
                "Mon 6/23 - Sunny - 31/17",
                "Tue 6/24 - Foggy - 21/8",
                "Wed 6/25 - Cloudy - 22/17",
                "Thurs 6/26 - Rainy - 18/11",
                "Fri 6/27 - Foggy - 21/10",
                "Sat 6/28 - TRAPPED IN WEATHERSTATION - 23/18",
                "Sun 6/29 - Sunny - 20/7"
        };
        List<String> weekForecast = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(data));

        // Now that we have some dummy forecast data, create an ArrayAdapter.
        // The ArrayAdapter will take data from a source (like our dummy forecast) and
        // use it to populate the ListView it's attached to.
        ArrayAdapter<String> forecastAdapter =
                new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                        getActivity(), // The current context (this activity)
                        R.layout.list_item_forecast, // The name of the layout ID.
                        R.id.list_item_forecast_textview, // The ID of the textview to populate.
                        weekForecast);

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        // Get a reference to the ListView, and attach this adapter to it.
        ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listview_forecast);
        listView.setAdapter(forecastAdapter);

        return rootView;
    }

    public class FetchWeatherTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        private final String LOG_TAG = FetchWeatherTask.class.getSimpleName();

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // These two need to be declared outside the try/catch
            // so that they can be closed in the finally block.
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
            BufferedReader reader = null;

            // Will contain the raw JSON response as a string.
            String forecastJsonStr = null;

            try {
                // Construct the URL for the OpenWeatherMap query
                // Possible parameters are avaiable at OWM's forecast API page, at
                // http://openweathermap.org/API#forecast
                URL url = new URL("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=94043&mode=json&units=metric&cnt=7");

                // Create the request to OpenWeatherMap, and open the connection
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                urlConnection.connect();

                // Read the input stream into a String
                InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                if (inputStream == null) {
                    // Nothing to do.
                    return null;
                }
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    // Since it's JSON, adding a newline isn't necessary (it won't affect parsing)
                    // But it does make debugging a *lot* easier if you print out the completed
                    // buffer for debugging.
                    buffer.append(line + "\n");
                }

                if (buffer.length() == 0) {
                    // Stream was empty.  No point in parsing.
                    return null;
                }
                forecastJsonStr = buffer.toString();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error ", e);
                // If the code didn't successfully get the weather data, there's no point in attemping
                // to parse it.
                return null;
            } finally {
                if (urlConnection != null) {
                    urlConnection.disconnect();
                }
                if (reader != null) {
                    try {
                        reader.close();
                    } catch (final IOException e) {
                        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error closing stream", e);
                    }
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

This code is taken from the following GIS Hub from an oline Android course:
https://github.com/udacity/Sunshine/blob/2.05-trigger-refresh/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/sunshine/app/ForecastFragment.java

Here's what the Logcat shows:

```
11-10 00:03:41.479  13081-13081/com.example.doblevxv5.sunny E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.doblevxv5.sunny/com.example.doblevxv5.sunny.ForecastFragment}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.doblevxv5.sunny.ForecastFragment cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2016)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2117)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:134)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1218)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4867)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.doblevxv5.sunny.ForecastFragment cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
            at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1068)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2007)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2117)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:134)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1218)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4867)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is the `AndroidManifest.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.doblevxv5.sunny" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:debuggable="true">
        <activity
            android:name=".ForecastFragment"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

When I run the app in my phone, it just stops. I cannot even keep the app open.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: show your manifest.xml

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.doblevxv5.sunny.ForecastFragment cannot be cast to android.app.Activity  -- main Problem, show your manifest.

Comment: this line here `com.example.doblevxv5.sunny.ForecastFragment cannot be cast to android.app.Activity` suggests a similar problem may of been solved [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20576747/fragment-cannot-be-cast-to-android-app-activity)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this :

```
android:name=".ForecastFragment"
```

With this :

```
android:name=".MainActivity"
```

**Note :** Only register Activities in AndroidManifest.xml no need to register Fragment,Fragment is part of activity so which directly call from activity without register in AndroidManifext.xml

Answer (score 1):

Your log clearly said

```
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.doblevxv5.sunny/com.example.doblevxv5.sunny.ForecastFragment}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.doblevxv5.sunny.ForecastFragment cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
```

`ForcastFragment` is not an `Activity` it's an `Fragment` and you cant register it on `manifest.xml`

So, better to create one `Activity` and take one `FrameLayout` and load your `ForcastFragment` on your `Activity` at Run time and register your Activity in your `manifest.xml.`

Answer (score 1):

You cannot declare `Fragment` in the `manifest`. In manifest remove  `android:name=".ForecastFragment"` and in place of `ForecaseFragment`  specify your `Activity` name.

Answer (score 0):

What is happening here is that you are trying to instantiate a fragment as an activity.

Your class ForecastFragment is an extension of a fragment as the code states. A fragment forms part of an activities layout, as such it must be part of an activity so that it can be instantiated as a view.

Check out the main activity they provide in the course - https://github.com/udacity/Sunshine/blob/2.05-trigger-refresh/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/sunshine/app/MainActivity.java

Answer (score 0):

Refer the following link it shows How to create and execute the fragment and mention the activity in the manifest

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_fragments.htm

Answer (score 0):

You should focus on this line of your error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.doblevxv5.sunny.ForecastFragment cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
            at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1068)
```

Your class is a Fragment, not an Activity. Try using:

```
public class ForecastFragment extends FragmentActivity{
...
}
```

On the link you provided, there are multiple activities, you only picked one .java file, there is also a second .java file called MainActivity.
https://github.com/udacity/Sunshine/blob/2.05-trigger-refresh/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/sunshine/app/MainActivity.java
You should read how Android works: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html
Your application is based on activities, think of an Activity as the pages of the book, think of a Main Activity as the first page of the book and think of a fragment as the content of that book.